# Mock MVC javax.validation test

Tags: validation, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I would like to mock my validation to test.

Size validation doesn't run in my test. Max size of id is 40 character, and I wait for an exception when I test it with 42 long id.

**MyObject.java**

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 40)
private String id;
```

**MyTest.java:**

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator; // javax.validation.Validator

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MyController).build();
}

@Test
public void Test() throws Exception {
    myObject.setId(StringUtils.repeat("k", 42);
    mockMvc.perform(post(MY_URL)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject)))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_WITH_UTF8));
}
```

I already mocked every necessary service. These are in XML files like this:

```
<bean id="mockValidator" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="javax.validation.Validator"/>
</bean>
```

But I got this message:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
```

From UI, everything works fine.

Comment: 1) what is the full stack trace for the exception you're encountering?

Comment: 2) why are you mocking the `Validator`?

Comment: 3) if you are using the `standaloneSetup()` method from `MockMvc`, then there is no point in mocking anything in the `ApplicationContext`, since the `standaloneSetup()` does not use your `ApplicationContext` at all. That's why it's "stand alone". If you want to use your own `ApplicationContext`, you need to use the `webAppContextSetup()` method from `MockMvcBuilders`.

Comment: 4) what is the signature of the controller method you are testing?

Comment: @BravoNine, did you solve this question? I am already using webAppContextSetup() but it is not working yet

Comment: How do you instantiate MyController ? Via @InjectMock or @Autowired?